# CMake generation on a Linux remote machine from VS19 does not work

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to generate a CMake project from Visual Studio 2019 to compile on a Linux remote machine. I defined the remote machine at the `CMakeSettings.json`. The CMake generation is going well, but just right when it is finished it rises the following error:

```
Extracted includes paths.
Extracted CMake variables.
Extracted source files and headers.
**Error: CMake file API parsing response files failed.**
```

I'm running the Visual Studio from my **Windows 10** computer. 
The odd thing is that when I am trying to generate the same project from another **Windows 7** computer the CMake generation finishes fine.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What specific version of VS 2019 are you using? Version 16.2.0? Version 16.2.2?

Comment: I'm using version 16.2.3 on my Windows 10 computer. On the windows 7 (where the CMake generation works) the VS version is 16.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is similar to the errors mentioned in a Visual Studio 2019 bug [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/576564/cmake-cache-cannot-be-opened-cmake-file-api-respon.html), related to CMake cache:

> “The cache for the current configuration could not be opened. See the
>   Error List for details.”
>
> [...]
>
> 1> CMake generation started for configuration: ‘MakeWin’.
>
> 1> Error: CMake file API response index file not found

This was reported in VS 2019 Version 16.0.

Microsoft released a fix for this issue, I believe in Version [16.2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#--visual-studio-2019-version-1621). If you upgrade your VS 2019 to the latest version, it may resolve the error you are seeing.

Comment: I don't think it is exaclly the same error... And also I'm using version 16.2.3